# Windows Service with DI - Repository injection

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, windows-services

I have a Windows service that is designed for Dependency Injection. The service runs several threaded timers, each of which polls a database and sometimes processes records in it.

One of the dependencies injected into the service is a Repository object which gives the required access to the database. The repository in turn encapsulates an Entity Framework DbContext.

Currently, an instance of the repository is injected when the service starts and remains available until it stops. I don't like this for two reasons:

- The DbContext lies idle most of the time but keeps a database connection open
- The DbContext becomes stale; external changes to the data already read into it are not reflected

I would like to change the way the repository is managed so that each invocation of a timer's execute method gets a fresh repository instance while keeping the repository as an injectable service.

My preferred approach is to inject a RepositoryFactory object rather than the repository so that the timer execute method can create its own repository. However, although the repository instance is created successfully, and the first access to the database through it (a GET) succeeds, the next database access (another GET contained within an UPDATE method) fails as the DbContext appears to have been disposed.

Can anyone cast any light on why this is happening, and suggest a solution? I'm open to using a pattern other than Factory if it meets the instantiation requirements.

```
//DI configuration
public static void AddRepository(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, RepositoryFactory>(Factory);
}

private static readonly Func<IServiceProvider, RepositoryFactory> Factory = (_serviceProvider) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("ServiceProvider instantiated: {0}", _serviceProvider != null);
    return new RepositoryFactory(_serviceProvider);
};

//Windows service constructor
public AllocationService(IRepositoryFactory factory, IMapperConfiguration mapperConfig)
{
    _repositoryFactory = factory;
    _mapperConfig = mapperConfig as MapperConfiguration;
    InitializeComponent();
}

//Timer execution method
private void _registrationTimer_Elapsed(object stateObject)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry(Constants.AllocationSourceName, string.Format("Registration Timer Elapsed on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId), EventLogEntryType.Information, (int)UseCaseType.Register);

    try
    {
        using (var repository = _repositoryFactory.Create())
        {
            //query the database for Approved Assets, 
            var list = repository.GetRegistrations(Status.Approved);
            EventLog.WriteEntry(Constants.AllocationSourceName, string.Format("{0} registrations with status=Approved", list.Count()), EventLogEntryType.Information, (int)UseCaseType.Register);

            foreach (var registration in list)
            {
                try
                {
                    //some processing removed here for simplicity

                    //update database
                    registration.Status = Status.Allocated;
                    //exception thrown here (see below)
                    repository.UpdateRegistration(registration);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log any problems and continue
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(Constants.AllocationSourceName, ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error, (int)UseCaseType.Register);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log any problems on saving
        EventLog.WriteEntry(Constants.AllocationSourceName, ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error, (int)UseCaseType.Register);
    }
}

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'MyDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.get_ServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.<.ctor>b__2_0()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at RegistryApp.Repository.Repository.ProcessAsset(Asset asset) in C:\svn\Client Applications\ITC\RegistryApp\RegistryApp.Repository\Repository.cs:line 364
   at RegistryApp.Repository.Repository.UpdateAsset(Asset asset) in C:\svn\Client Applications\ITC\RegistryApp\RegistryApp.Repository\Repository.cs:line 270
```